# How to Properly Insert Variables in Equations

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following formula for script which others on the site have helped me develop. I am working on a spreadsheet that will have 30+ buttons but utilize this same formula with only a few values being swapped out.

```js
//Set Formula in Column H for Mastic Calculation.

sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,8).setFormula('=IF(AND($F$21="Flow Line",F' + (lastrow+1) + '/8=TRUNC(F' + (lastrow+1) + '/8)),(((F' + (lastrow+1) + '/8)+(G' + (lastrow+1) + '/2))*3),IF(AND($F$21="Flow Line",(F' + (lastrow+1) + '-6)/8=TRUNC((F' + (lastrow+1) + '-6)/8)),((((F' + (lastrow+1) + '-6)/8)+1+(G' + (lastrow+1) + '/2))*3),IF(AND($F$21="Flow Line",(F' + (lastrow+1) + '-12)/8=TRUNC((F' + (lastrow+1) + '-12)/8)),((((F' + (lastrow+1) + '-12)/8)+2+(G' + (lastrow+1) + '/2))*3),if(AND($F$21="Flow Line",(F' + (lastrow+1) + '-18)/8=TRUNC((F' + (lastrow+1) + '-18)/8)),((((F' + (lastrow+1) + '-18)/8)+3+(G' + (lastrow+1) + '/2))*3),IF(AND($F$21="Full Mastic",F' + (lastrow+1) + '/8=TRUNC(F' + (lastrow+1) + '/8)),(((F' + (lastrow+1) + '/8)+(G' + (lastrow+1) + '/2))*5),if(AND($F$21="Full Mastic",(F' + (lastrow+1) + '-6)/8=TRUNC((F' + (lastrow+1) + '-6)/8)),((((F' + (lastrow+1) + '-6)/8)+3+(G' + (lastrow+1) + '/2))*5),if(AND($F$21="Full Mastic",(F' + (lastrow+1) + '-12)/8=TRUNC((F' + (lastrow+1) + '-12)/8)),((((F' + (lastrow+1) + '-12)/8)+3+(G' + (lastrow+1) + '/2))*5),if(AND($F$21="Full Mastic",(F' + (lastrow+1) + '-18)/8=TRUNC((F' + (lastrow+1) + '-18)/8)),((((F' + (lastrow+1) + '-18)/8)+3+(G' + (lastrow+1) + '/2))*5),0))))))))');
```

I would like to be able to swap out a couple of the integers and make them variable. I have tried inserting this at the beginning of the script:

```js
//Set Variable for Flow Line Mastic

halfmastic = 3
```

And other variations of this such as setting it as var but I can't seem to get it to work correctly when I insert it in place of an integer in the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would look like below.

```js
var halfMastic = 3;

...' + (lastrow+1) + '-18)/8)+' + halfMastic + '+(G' + (lastrow+1) + '/2))*5),0...
```